# Automate assignment of multiple values from the $_POST variable

Tags: php, post, dynamic

I just wrote the following code:

```
<?php


        $email = checkPost("email");
        $username = checkPost("username");
        $firstname = checkPost("firstname");
        $lastname = checkPost("lastname");
        $zipcode = checkPost("zipcode");


        echo("EMAIL: ".$email."  USERENAME: ".$username);
        function checkPost($formData) {
            if (isset($_POST[$formData])) {
                return $_POST[$formData];   
            }
        }

    ?>
```

What I'd like to do is eliminate all those calls to checkPost() at the top.  This code below doesn't require any knowledge of the fields in the form that submits to it, it just loops through all of the fields and spits out their values.

```
<?php
// loop through every form field
while( list( $field, $value ) = each( $_POST )) {
   // display values
   if( is_array( $value )) {
      // if checkbox (or other multiple value fields)
      while( list( $arrayField, $arrayValue ) = each( $value ) {
         echo "<p>" . $arrayValue . "</p>\n";
      }
   } else {
      echo "<p>" . $value . "</p>\n";
   }
}
?>
```

I want to modify this code such that variables like $email, etc would be created and assigned values on the fly.  Like say you run this on a form that has "email" and "name".  You won't have to give php a variable name $email or $name.  It will just loop through and for "email" create and fill a variable named $email and so on and so forth.

Am I dreaming?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<p>', htmlspecialchars($key), ' = ', htmlspecialchars($value), '</p>';
}
```

I think that's what you're looking for anyway.  Basically, we just loop through all `$_POST` elements and display them.  You can of course do whatever you need with them, within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use...

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);
```

...but I **don't recommend it**. This will unpack the array's keys into the scope it is in. I've set it to *not* overwrite existing variables.

You should explicitly define your variables.

Comment: Thank you.  And I definitely agree on explicitly defining your variables.  Maybe it's the ADD in me or something but I'm always just kind of wondering what's possible even when it's somewhat besides the point.